# How to call the percentage of a number in a PHP variable to HTML/CSS?

Tags: php, css

I am trying to pass the percentage in HTML/CSS but I can not succeed.

I am trying:

```
<?php
$myPercentage = 100;
?>
```

I am trying to pass the variable in HTML/CSS. I want my progress bar to increase/decrease according to the PHP value.

```
<style>
  .bar-4 {width:70%; height: 18px; background-color: red}

   /* Here is the problem, the above progress bar 4 is working and its width increases to 70% but below code is not working. */

  .bar-5 {width: <?php echo $myPercentage;?>%; height: 18px; background-color: #4CAF50;}

</style>
```

Your idea or suggestions would be welcome.
Thank You.

Comment: What do you see in generated `style` block?

Comment: PHP runs on the server when the page is first loaded.

Comment: How are you updating `$percentage`?

Comment: Is your html being run through the php parser or just read in and echoed, eg `echo file_get_contents('mystyle.html')`?  If it is something like the latter then your code isn't being processed. Note though updating that variable in php will not update an already loaded page (user would need to reload to see an update)

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the reply. I know the percentage formula a/t*100, suppose $percentage is 100, and I am giving this value to css. How can I get dynamic bar then like bar-4 in my css.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to change the element style dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question lacks some important data, but here are the general guidelines that will make it work:

1. To have a dynamic variable in the CSS block, you need to be echo the relevant part, or include it **in the PHP file** (and not on a separate CSS file)
2. The value given to the variable must come before the CSS block.

So for example, your PHP file should have something like:

```
<?php
$myPercentage = 100;
?>
<style>
  .bar-5 {width: <?php echo $myPercentage;?>%;}
</style>
```

3. For cleaner code, the rest of .bar-5 CSS is better to stay in your CSS file, and only the dynamic values should be printed as inline CSS.